# Changing the year of a slice/series obtained from a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, datetime, replace, slice, series

I got a large dataset which is the imported schedule (spanning multiple years) for my team. I cleaned the data (made it long instead of wide), however I encounter a problem.

**First an explanation of the data:**

- 'year' and 'period' are obtained from the split sheetname. Both strings.
- 'week' the week of the year, obtained from the roster. Float.
- 'date' converted from string, for which I wrote a function as the dates were in Dutch and needed to be normalized, no year was defined so therefore the year from the first column is used. After processing; datetime format.
- 'shift' the type of shift it belongs to. S1 > early, S2 > late, S3 > night.
- Each rule is assigned to one of my employees, those names are erased for privacy reasons.
- I've written a class with several methods that apply rules our government enforces on schedules.

[image: preprocessed_data DF]

**Now my problem:**

As you can see: entries 1137 and 1138 should belong to the year 2022. But how do I change this easily? I tried:

```py
for week, date in prepocessed_data_merged[['week', 'date']].values:
    # There are always more than 52 weeks in a year.
    # If the month of the date in week 52 is 1 (Jan), then something is wrong.
    if (week == 52) & (date.month == 1):
        prepocessed_data_merged.loc[(prepocessed_data_merged['week'] == week)
                                    & (prepocessed_data_merged['date']), 'date'] = ???
```

But as you might expect this returns a series since there are three shifts on a day, so three entries of a date that need their year changed. So, how does one change the year of a selected series/slice, simultaneously changing it in the dataframe?

I know I can use: `dt.replace(year=current_year+1)` but how do I enforce this `replace` on this selected series in the preprocessed_data DF? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```py
cond = prepocessed_data_merged['week'].eq(52) & prepocessed_data_merged['date'].dt.month.eq(1)
prepocessed_data_merged.loc[cond, 'date'] += pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

Comment: I tried this it but it didn't work, since there is no 'month' column. If there is a way to access it from the 'date' column, tell me! 
However, I found something else, which worked. I will answer it to this question. If you have a suggestion for making it more pythonic, please answer, since I have the feeling it could be better.

Comment: Yes, you use `prepocessed_data_merged['date'].dt.month`

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you did here. This does solve the problem, however partially. See I do not want to change the year in the 'year' column. I want to change the year in the 'date' column, which belongs to a datetime object. Reason for this being is that I want to filter the DF by years, so I would like to obtain all rosters in 2021. With your snippet, the last entries for that year would dissapear.

Comment: Might I add that I will implement your way of filing conditions. Way neater and more clear.

Comment: Not a problem. See my edited answer

Comment: Thank you very much, this does exactly what I want whilst being very clean!